# How to make a np.array of N diagonal matrices

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I want to make an array of N diagonal matrices with M dimension, for example for N=2 and M=3,

the array should be like this: np.array([[[1, 0, 0],[0, 2, 0],[0, 0, 3]],
[[5, 0, 0],[0, 6, 0],[0, 0, 7]]])

with random elements on the main diagonal

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating the output array of shape `(n, m, m)` and then indexing the leading diagonal of the last two axes with [numpy.arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

def generate_diagonal_matrices_nin17(n, m):
    idx_n = np.arange(n)
    idx_m = np.arange(m)
    
    out = np.zeros((n, m, m))
    
    out[idx_n[:, None], idx_m, idx_m] = rng.random((n, m))
    return out
```

Timings (with `generate_diagonal_matrices` from user3046211's answer):

```
%timeit -n 1000 generate_diagonal_matrices_nin17(100, 100)
%timeit -n 1000 generate_diagonal_matrices(100, 100)
```

```
441 µs ± 73.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
1.44 ms ± 645 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an array of random numbers of size `N X M`. Now using `np.diag` we can create the diagonal matrices and then stack them up together. Here's how you can do.

```
import numpy as np

def generate_diagonal_matrices(N, M):
    # Generate random numbers for the diagonals
    diagonals = np.random.rand(N, M)

    # Create diagonal matrices
    matrices = [np.diag(diagonals[i]) for i in range(N)]

    # Convert list of matrices to a numpy array
    return np.array(matrices)

N = 2
M = 3
result = generate_diagonal_matrices(N, M)
print(result)
```

which results in below with random elements on the diagonal side with an overall time complexity of `O(N x M^2)`.

```
[[[0.5663498  0.         0.        ]
  [0.         0.74251659 0.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.31700871]]

 [[0.69622446 0.         0.        ]
  [0.         0.6330884  0.        ]
  [0.         0.         0.55743844]]]
```